# Retrieving data from a huge table

Tags: python, pandas, split

Let me decribe the task: Each column represents the ship (name of the column is the name of a ship and rows are containers). The name of the ship is in the form nn: xxxxxx (ttttttt). The containers are represented in the form aa-bb-cccccccc/yyyy/xx@ddddddddd.ee, where bb is the name of the final destination of a container. My task is to calculate the number of containers whose final destination is Japan, so I have to retrieve bb from the containers form and count them. My idea is to create another table, which will be created by the function split (with '-' as the splitting caption) and then count it simply by adding +1 when bb is in the cell. Here is some code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("dane.csv", sep=';')

shape = list(df.shape)
for i in range(0, shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, shape[1]):
        obj = df.iloc[i, j].split('-')
```

I get tracebacks as such:

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,31,32,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,43,44,45,46,47,49,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
```

and

```
'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I improve it?

Input file, first 5 rows of 1st column:

```
1: Brandenburg (Post-Panamax)
ES-NL-10633096/1938/X1@hkzydbezon.dk/6749
BE-BR-61613986/3551/B1@oqk.bf/39927
PH-SA-39552610/2436/A1@venagi.hr/80578
PA-AE-59814691/4881/X1@zhicvzvksl.cl/25247
```

And some cells are empty.

Comment: Can you include a portion of your input file here... Maybe 5 lines?

Comment: @ScottBoston it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's us regular expressions with `extract` then `value_counts` and you can filter your result to get your proper destinations.

```
from io import StringIO

intxt = StringIO("""1: Brandenburg (Post-Panamax)
ES-NL-10633096/1938/X1@hkzydbezon.dk/6749
BE-BR-61613986/3551/B1@oqk.bf/39927
PH-SA-39552610/2436/A1@venagi.hr/80578
PA-AE-59814691/4881/X1@zhicvzvksl.cl/25247""")

df = pd.read_csv(intxt, names=['data'])

df['data'].str.extract('^[a-zA-z]{2}-([a-zA-Z]{2})')[0].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
AE    1
BR    1
SA    1
NL    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```